# Silverstripe Front-end Search Ajaxification

Tags: silverstripe

I want to show the default SilverStripe site search box in a modal and then upon submission of form want to show the search results in the same modal rather them showing on the page.
[default search on front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyCSs.jpg)
I was following the approach where I created a page type ...

```
AjaxFormPage extends Page {}
class AjaxFormPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {}
```

1) In here I did the init method to load `jQuery`.

2) Created Form (basically, the same search form from the `ContentControllerSearchExtension` class and pasted in here.

3) Also copied the results function from the `ContentControllerSearchExtension` as below:

```
public function resultsAjax($data, $form, $request) {
        //$this->request->isAjax()
        //Director::is_ajax()
        if (Director::is_ajax()) {
    $data = array(
        'Results' => $form->getResults(),
        'Query' => DBField::create_field('Text', $form->getSearchQuery()),
        'Title' => _t('SearchForm.SearchResults', 'Search Results')
    );
    return $this->owner->customise($data)->renderWith(array('Page_results', 'Page'));
        } else {
            return "Not Ajax";
        }
}
```

}

The Form is going to the following URL
`/new-ajax-form-page/SearchForm/?Search=asdasd&action_AjaxSubmit=Go`

And I am getting the following waring 1, 2 and 3 for each argument to `resultsAjax` method

```
[Warning] Missing argument 1 for AjaxFormPage_Controller::resultsAjax(), called in /var/www/projects/xxxx/framework/view/ViewableData.php on line 466 and defined
GET /new-ajax-form-page/SearchForm/?Search=asdasd&action_AjaxSubmit=Go

Line 137 in /var/www/projects/xxxx/mysite/AjaxFormPage.php

[Warning] Missing argument 2 for AjaxFormPage_Controller::resultsAjax(), called in /var/www/projects/xxxx/framework/view/ViewableData.php on line 466 and defined
GET /new-ajax-form-page/SearchForm/?Search=asdasd&action_AjaxSubmit=Go

Line 137 in /var/www/projects/xxxx/mysite/AjaxFormPage.php

[Warning] Missing argument 3 for AjaxFormPage_Controller::resultsAjax(), called in /var/www/projects/xxxx/framework/view/ViewableData.php on line 466 and defined
GET /new-ajax-form-page/SearchForm/?Search=asdasd&action_AjaxSubmit=Go

Line 137 in /var/www/projects/xxxx/mysite/AjaxFormPage.php
```

Any help how to make it working will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't inject too many concerns about ajax in your backend code. An ajax form should work fundamentally the same as any other form, except for the behaviours that are applied to it on the frontend. This helps with uniformity throughout your code and also allows your forms to degrade gracefully (i.e. they still work without ajax).

In your case, I think all you need is to make the `results()` function provided by `ContentControllerSearchExtension` ajax-aware.

Start by overloading `results()` in `Page_Controller`.

```
public function results($data, $form, $request) {
    $data = array(
        'Results' => $form->getResults(),
        'Query' => DBField::create_field('Text', $form->getSearchQuery()),
        'Title' => _t('SearchForm.SearchResults', 'Search Results')
    );
    return $this->owner->customise($data)->renderWith(array('Page_results', 'Page'));
}
```

Now, instead of returning a full template, check to see if the request is ajax, and if so, return a partial.

```
public function results($data, $form, $request) {
    // ...

    if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
      return $this->customise($data)->renderWith('AjaxSearchResults');
    }

    return $this->owner->customise($data)->renderWith(array('Page_results', 'Page'));
}
```

Where `AjaxSearchResults.ss` is a template containing only the snippet of HTML you want to inject into the modal window.

Your JS will look something like this (excuse my rusty jQuery):

```
$('.myForm').submit(e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = $(this).serialize();
  const $form = $(this);
  $.ajax(
    $form.attr('action'),
    {    
      type: 'GET',
      data,
    } 
  })
  .done(response => {
    $('#some-div').html(response);
  });
);
```

Relevant: https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/ajax-behaviour-and-viewabledata

UPDATE: Gist: https://gist.github.com/unclecheese/dcb3777e929a429e906b8b5c9ffc9c0b

Comment: Hi UncleCheese, 

Thanks for the response. I started creating a new Controller as:

class AjaxSearchResults extends Page {
}
class AjaxSearchResults_Controller extends Page_Controller {
    
    public function results($data, $form, $request) {
    // ...
    if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
      return $this->customise($data)->renderWith('AjaxSearchResults');
    }

    return $this->owner->customise($data)->renderWith(array('Page_results', 'Page'));
}    
}

Also created an ss file and a Js file 

ss file contains the HTML that i want to render as results.

Comment: How my AjaxSearchResults Controller will be aware that this results method that i have added in here is to retrieve the native silvestripe search results. Do i need to have some reference of 'ContentControllerSearchExtension' somewhere ??

Comment: Hi UC,

I used the above code and now in the response. ... i m getting the full html code of the page (on console.log) from which i m loading the search modal.

Instead of the search result it's spitting out the html of the page from the which the modal is being loaded to perform the search on the console.log.

Any clue why it is doing this instead of spitting out the search results.

Comment: Do i need to add the followin code in my results method ???

$data = array(
        'Results' => $form->getResults(),
        'Query' => DBField::create_field('Text', $form->getSearchQuery()),
        'Title' => _t('SearchForm.SearchResults', 'Search Results')
    );

Comment: Even this method is not getting called:
------------------------------------------------

Comment: public function results($data, $form, $request) {
    // ...
    SS_Log::log("logs if coming here ".$data.$form.$request, SS_Log::WARN);
    $data = array(
        'Results' => $form->getResults(),
        'Query' => DBField::create_field('Text', $form->getSearchQuery()),
        'Title' => _t('SearchForm.SearchResults', 'Search Results')
    );        
    
    
    if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
      return $this->customise($data)->renderWith('AjaxSearchResults');
    }

    return $this->owner->customise($data)->renderWith(array('Page_results', 'Page'));
}

Comment: In my <form i have the following action defined <form method="get" action="/new-ajax-search-results/results" id="search-form" name="search-form">

Comment: When i do print the console.log("This is the data"+data+"<>>><>"); from the js file its coming blank as well. So my fear is that the results method from the AjaxSearchResults controller is never getting called.

Comment: Have updated the response with a gist that I have confirmed working in SS 3.6.

Comment: Hi UncleCheese, Thanks for your kind support. I am not able to make it working. I have a Modal as below

<div class="reveal large" id="search-form" data-reveal data-close-on-click="false">
Here i stick in the form with action as /home/results/ (see below). 
    <form id="search-form" name="search-form" action="/home/results" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
I have the existing controller (myBlogControllerExtension.php) where i have pasted your results method.

I can confirm that in my Jquery ($form) is undefined and $data is blank.

Comment: This is myJquery.

$('#search-form').on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    const data = $(this).serialize();
    const $form = $(this);
                  alert("coming here 2 "+data);
                  alert("coming here "+$form.attr('action'));

data is blank and $form.attr('action') is undefined :(

Comment: [Warning] Missing argument 2 for SgBlogControllerExtension::results()

Comment: [Warning] Missing argument 3 for SgBlogControllerExtension::results()
GET /home/results/?Search=dfgd

Comment: [Notice] Undefined variable: request
GET /home/results/?Search=dfgd

Comment: You can't overload an extension method in another extension. You can only overload an extension method in a class. Why are you putting it in the extension? This is for site search, right? Just put it in Page_Controller.

Comment: So I have to create a new Page_Controller let's say AjaxSearchController that will extent the Page or ContentController ???

Yes, it is for the sitesearch basically I want to load the searchform in a Modal and then as soon as user clicks the Go button, it performs the search (staying on the same Modal) and shows the results in the same modal (below the search box).

Comment: So basically my search form is not same typical form that we have with SS default. Instead it has to be loaded in a Modal